# A Somewhat Foolish Poem

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction, sudoku, seasonal

Your task is to solve the Sudoku and complete the missing words in the following poem.[image]

- Classic Sudoku: Each row column and box contains the digits 1-9.
- XV-rules: Digits separated by V must add to 5. Digits separated by X must add to 10. There is no negative constraint (e.g. a 3-7 domino can appear with or without an X-clue). In this puzzle only one V-clue is provided.
- FUN FACT: the following URL describes a little-known trick for solving Classic Sudoku.
  https://www.youtube.com/watch? v = d Q w * w * W g * c Q

HINT:

> Forget about the Sudoku. Rand Al Thor's partial answer has already extracted all the useful information available.

Comment: [Nice one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) <-- link may contain spoilers

Comment: @Randal'Thor You must be very familiar with the given URL, because it seems like you found the URL before you solved the puzzle :)

Comment: @LukasRotter It's memorable to me because of its multiple doubleyous. Combined with last Thursday's date ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Completed Sudoku:

> [image]

This is confirmed by the FUN FACT, which refers to

> a [rickroll video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) with the characters **4,9,X** removed. The green cells in the Sudoku grid are 4, 9, and two numbers which could have an X between.

Step-by-step solution:

> [image]

Comment: You’re most of the way there. All you need is to complete the poem and the check mark is yours

Comment: @happystar I'm pretty stuck on how the poem relates to anything else. (It contains 51 asterisks, FWIW - I assume those are all supposed to be words, but also somehow to connect with the numbers in the grid ...)